# WebSecurity.ChangePassword returning FALSE value

Tags: asp.net, html, webmatrix

I can't figure out why my WebSecurity.ChangePassword is not working. Here's the piece of code I'm working on.

```
     if (WebSecurity.ChangePassword(USER, oldpass, password)) {
                    Response.Redirect("~/SuperAdmin");
                    return;
                }else {
                    ModelState.AddFormError(USER); 
// I put the each WebSecurity.ChangePassword parameter to this parameter to check whether 
//each parameter valid or not (print it out)                   

 }
```

and for each parameter of WebSecurity.ChangePassword, I retrieve it from the database as follows

```
 if(IsPost){
    Validation.RequireField("email", "Masukkan email");
    Validation.RequireField("password", "Masukkan Password");
    Validation.RequireField("userid", "user ID tidak ada!");

    email = Request.Form["email"];
    password = Request.Form["password"];
    userId = Request.Form["userId"];

    if(Validation.IsValid()){
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var updateCommand2 = "UPDATE UserProfile  SET Email=@0 WHERE UserId=@1";
        db.Execute(updateCommand2, email,userId);
        var USER = db.QueryValue("SELECT a.Email  FROM UserProfile a, webpages_Membership b   WHERE a.UserId=b.UserId AND a.UserId= @0", userId);
        var oldpass = db.QueryValue("SELECT Password  FROM webpages_Membership  WHERE UserId = @0", userId);
```

Can anyone tell me what seems to be the problem here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The WebPages Membership has everything built you do not need to get the users email address and password (I am guessing the email address is the username right?) The ChangePassword method takes 3 arguments. which is UserName, CurrentPassword, NewPassword.

The reason your getting false is because your getting the old password from the database based on the users current Id, but the old password does not match the users current password because old one is encrypted and you're not encrypting the one they submit (in fact you don't even have a field for them to enter their current password).

The WebPages Membership provider will do all the updating you do not need open the database and update the users password, the weird thing you're doing is telling the user to enter a new password but not asking for the current one! Here see this for more information:

http://www.thecodingguys.net/reference/asp/websecurity-changepassword

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user you are trying to change password for is not LockedOut. You can check it by this

```
select * from aspnet_membership
where 
 IsLockedOut = 1
```